# How To Accommodate ItemsSource and Items

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Controls such as the `ListBox` have an `ItemsSource` property which you can bind to

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxColours" ItemsSource="{Binding Colours}" />
```

It also has an `Items` property however, which can be used to add items in the code behind

```
ListBoxColours.Items.Add("Red");
```

I'm creating a CustomControl which has a `ListBox` in. I've exposed the `ItemSource` in my control to allow the user to bind the items to a property in their `ViewModel`.

```
<ListBox
     x:Name="PART_ListBox"
     ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:TextBoxComboControl}}"
     SelectionMode="Single" />
```

...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(TextBoxComboControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable) GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

...

```
<local:TextBoxComboControl ItemsSource="{Binding Colours}" />
```

I would like to add the ability for a user to add items in the code behind as well though, incase they don't want to use a binding. I was wondering how the `ItemSource` / `Items` properties interact with eachother. In order to allow them to use either peoprty, I would have to bind the `ListBox` items to both properties within my control.

Comment: From the Remarks section on the [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items(v=vs.110).aspx) page: *Note that you use either the Items or the ItemsSource property to specify the collection that should be used to generate the content of your ItemsControl. When the ItemsSource property is set, the Items collection is made read-only and fixed-size.*

Comment: Actually, I'd say you just would have to "relay" the property. `... Items { get => PART_ListBox.Items; set => PART_ListBox.Items = value; }` ...

Comment: @Fildor Note that Items is a readonly property.

Comment: Ooops. Missed that, sorry. @Clemens is right. Leave out the setter, Ralt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListBox` derives from `Selector` which derives from `ItemsControl` .

If you look at the source code to `ItemsControl`:

- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,54366ee76d2f1106
- http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl@cs/1458001/ItemsControl@cs

You can see:

```
/// <summary> 
///     ItemsSource specifies a collection used to generate the content of
/// this control.  This provides a simple way to use exactly one collection 
/// as the source of content for this control. 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks> 
///     Any existing contents of the Items collection is replaced when this
/// property is set. The Items collection will be made ReadOnly and FixedSize.
///     When ItemsSource is in use, setting this property to null will remove
/// the collection and restore use to Items (which will be an empty ItemCollection). 
///     When ItemsSource is not in use, the value of this property is null, and
/// setting it to null has no effect. 
/// </remarks>
    [Bindable(true), CustomCategory("Content")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)] 
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return Items.ItemsSource; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) 
            { 
                ClearValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            } 
            else
            {
                SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
            } 
        }
    }
```

If you look at the `Items` property which is of type `ItemsCollection` ... it can be in one of two modes (ItemsSource mode or "direct" mode).

```
/// <summary>
/// ItemCollection will contain items shaped as strings, objects, xml nodes,
/// elements, as well as other collections.  (It will not promote elements from
/// contained collections; to "flatten" contained collections, assign a
/// <seealso cref="System.Windows.Data.CompositeCollection"/> to
/// the ItemsSource property on the ItemsControl.)
/// A <seealso cref="System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl"/> uses the data
/// in the ItemCollection to generate its content according to its ItemTemplate.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// When first created, ItemCollection is in an uninitialized state, neither
/// ItemsSource-mode nor direct-mode.  It will hold settings like SortDescriptions and Filter
/// until the mode is determined, then assign the settings to the active view.
/// When uninitialized, calls to the list-modifying members will put the
/// ItemCollection in direct mode, and setting the ItemsSource will put the
/// ItemCollection in ItemsSource mode.
/// </remarks>
```

There's an internal member called `_isUsingItemsSource` which gets set/cleared to track which mode it is in - this makes various method/properties behave differently depending on the mode.

"Items" are accessed via a `CollectionView` (which is kept in the `_collectionView` member) - this either points to an `InnerItemCollectionView` which wraps access to the direct items , or a `CollectionView` created with `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultCollectionView` when `SetItemsSource` is called due to an "itemssource" being set.

You are most probably deriving from `Control` so you need to provide the similar behaviour. Maybe you can derive from `ItemsControl` to gain that behaviour....depends on your control of course if that is suitable.